# Animated emoji name doesn't display as i wanted

Tags: discord.js, emoji

So simple emoji command where it's supposed to display it's information like name, id, link and etc you get the idea. Works all fine with default emojis and custom server emojis but the moment its animated the name changes from
"`<a:CS_Shrug:740861064257863690>`" to just "`:CS_Shrug:`" i know this has something with discord displaying stuff but is there anyway to get around this? People asked for code:

```js
let args = msg.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/); //slice message in an array
    if (args[1]) { //if theres something mentioned
        let newRawdata = fs.readFileSync('./emojis.json');
        let newData = JSON.parse(newRawdata);
        var findEmoji = Object.values(newData).find(object => object === args[1]) //just a file with all unicode emojis bc yes 
        if (args[1].startsWith("<:") && args[1].endsWith(">")) { //custom server emoji
            //not important code
        } else if (args[1].startsWith("<a:") && args[1].endsWith(">")){
            let ForBots = args[1]
            let namever1 = ForBots.replace('<a','')
            let namever2 = namever1.replace('>','')
            let namever3 = namever2.split(':')
            let name = namever3[1]
            let id = namever3[2]
            var inforEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#2ab94c')
            .setTitle('Emoji information')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Type', value: "`Animated server emoji`", inline: false },
                { name: 'Name', value: "`"+name+"`", inline: false },
                { name: 'ID', value: "`"+id+"`", inline: true },
                { name: 'For bots', value: "`"+args[1]+"`", inline: true }, //should display `<a:CS_Shrug:740861064257863690>` but instead `:CS_Shrug:`
                { name: 'Emoji link', value: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/"+id+".gif?/v=1", inline: false },
            )
            .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/'+id+'.gif?/v=1')
            .setFooter("C.U.A.L - Bot| ;help", 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/864287060424785941/872600493082415124/Avatar_1.png')
            msg.channel.send(inforEmbed2)
        } else if (findEmoji) { //default emoji
            //more none important code
        } else msg.reply("donno wtf this is") // wasnt an emoji
     } else msg.reply("Gotta give me something first")
```

Comment: Can we have your command code?

Comment: i mean it doesnt have to do anything with the command but sure

Comment: FYI: theres nothing wrong with the command, ive tested it with logs. Its the moment it gets sent it changes

Comment: In the embed log too? It was good?

Comment: if i do `console.log(args[1])` it gives me the correct way (`<a:CS_Shrug:740861064257863690>`)

Comment: And if you log the embed? What returns?

Comment: says the same `<a:CS_Shrug:740861064257863690>`